# pentaho- update flag value based on comparison result from 2 data streams

Tags: pentaho, pdi

i have sample data Set 1 and set 2 as at the attached image, i want to compare set 1 with set 2 data, it the key(sectionid, itemid and rid ) is the same, look for the logdatetime, and the update the flagvalue ('1', with earlier logdatetime) from set 2 to set 1, what steps from the penatho pdi can help me to achieve this?

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHNLO.jpg)

Comment: if set1 and set2 is present in database. if yes, you can use database lookup and update component for the same. if no, you can insert the same in db and do the same.

Answer (score 1):

The step you are looking is called [`Merge Row (diff)`](http://wiki.pentaho.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=22184555).

Given two data flow, you specify the keys (sectionid, itemid and rid) and the values to compare (logdatetime). Then PDI will set a new field as identical, changed, new or deleted. Or course new depends on which of Set1 or Set2 was defined as "reference".

Two words of caution:

1. Both streams must have the same format (field name, order and type): Use the `Select Value` step for that.
2. Both streams must be sorted on the specified key(s): Use the `Sort row` step for that.